# CALayer animate contents between more than 2 images impossible?

Tags: ios, iphone, quartz-core, cakeyframeanimation

Does anyone has managed to animate the `contents` property of a `CALayer` between 3 images with successful interpolation. It seems that the animation is unable to manage interpolation between more than two images. My `CGImages` have all the same size.

```
        CAKeyframeAnimation * animation =
        [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
        animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
        animation.beginTime       = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;
        animation.duration        = duration;
        animation.fillMode        = kCAFillModeBoth;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

        CGFloat width1  = CGImageGetWidth(image1.CGImage);
        CGFloat height1 = CGImageGetHeight(image1.CGImage);

        CGFloat width2  = CGImageGetWidth(image2.CGImage);
        CGFloat height2 = CGImageGetHeight(image2.CGImage);

        CGFloat width3  = CGImageGetWidth(image3.CGImage);
        CGFloat height3 = CGImageGetHeight(image3.CGImage);

        NSLog(@"first: W:%f H:%f, second: W:%f H:%f, third: W:%f H:%f",width1,height1,width2,height2,width3,height3);


        animation.keyTimes        = @[@0.0,@0.1,@0.3,@0.6,@1.0];

        animation.values          =
        @[(id)image1.CGImage,
          (id)image1.CGImage,
          (id)image2.CGImage,
          (id)image2.CGImage,
          (id)image3.CGImage];
```

THE Log

```
2014-01-22 16:05:24.985 myApp[8527:60b] first: W:2592.000000 H:1936.000000, second: W:2592.000000 H:1936.000000, third: W:2592.000000 H:1936.000000
```

Comment: Unless I remember wrong, I have made it work with many, many images. I'm on a mobile device on my commute right now so I can't try it myself but one thing that sticks out to me is that your images are quite big. Do you mind testing with 100x100 images instead? (Also the general dislike of removedOnCompletion but that is not your problem, just a pet peeve of mine)

Comment: I'll try with smaller images right now

Comment: Indeed it works with 3 plain image. Looks like the image's size may be the issue here. I'll try again with bigger than 100px images